# eZ Publish Edit Header

Tags: php, ezpublish

My friend asked me if i could add a little piece of code to his website, his website is running on the eZ Publish platform which i have never actually used before.

I have spent the last few hours trying to figure out how to edit the header of the template for his website http://tenantstips.com/.

From the Admin/Design area i can see an option to add code to the footer of the page but not the header.

I have also tried finding the header file from within the FTP files and can't seem to see it.

If anyone is good with this platform and can help me add a little piece of code to the header of the above website that would appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to edit the files to do that. You can try via the design section in admin (depending on filesystem perms) but the best option is to edit the files via ssh or ftp.